# verify signature without need to original message (in java)

Tags: java, signature, verify

I want to sign a message and then I get the original message from the signature.
I find RSA & DSA signature in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/vstep4.html 
but their verify method use original data for verify and can not recover message from signature.
Is there any way to do it in Java or any free-library for Java?
thanks all.

Comment: It isn't possible to recover a message from the signature. The signature is almost always much shorter, so it can't possibly contain enough data. The signature will only validate the message, not reproduce it.

Comment: But for some signature methods it is possible to recover a message. for example RSA. see this page:(http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/iso/iso9796/RecoveredMessage.html) but iaik library is not free.

Comment: The word RSA appears in some of the algorithm names specified in ISO-9796, but it is not an RSA signature. But you are right, some signature algorithms do support message recovery. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BouncyCastle. It [supports ISO-9796-2](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html). And [ISO9796Test.java](http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/java/crypto/test/src/org/bouncycastle/crypto/test/ISO9796Test.java?view=markup) provides an example. Here is an excerpt that might help:

```
RSAKeyParameters pubParameters = new RSAKeyParameters(false, mod3, pub3);
RSAKeyParameters privParameters = new RSAKeyParameters(true, mod3, pri3);
RSAEngine rsa = new RSAEngine();
byte[] data;
ISO9796d2Signer eng = new ISO9796d2Signer(rsa, new RIPEMD128Digest());
eng.init(true, privParameters);
eng.update(msg4[0]);
eng.update(msg4, 1, msg4.length - 1);
data = eng.generateSignature();
eng.init(false, pubParameters);
eng.update(msg4[0]);
eng.update(msg4, 1, msg4.length - 1);
if (eng.hasFullMessage()) {
    eng = new ISO9796d2Signer(rsa, new RIPEMD128Digest());
    eng.init(false, pubParameters);
    if (!eng.verifySignature(sig4)) {
        // signature tampered with
    }
    byte[] message = eng.getRecoveredMessage(), 0, msg4);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have other problem too, when the length of input text for sign becomes large the verify can not do complete. How should this problem be solved?

Comment: Please ask a new question. Feel free to refer to this one. You will need to provide more detail such as algorithm,  message length,  expected behavior, actual behavior (any exception?), known differences between successful and failing cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482155/sign-the-large-message-and-verify-with-recover-message

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to ISO9796-2 digital signature scheme 1, trailer field 1, octet "BC" that doesn't require original message.

```
    RSAEngine rsa = new RSAEngine();
    //DS as SHA1
    Digest dig = new SHA1Digest();
    //3rd parameter "true" indicates implicit which means TF1(octet BC)
    ISO9796d2Signer eng = new ISO9796d2Signer(rsa, dig, true);
    eng.init(false, pubKeyParameter);

    eng.verifySignature(sig);  // if the signature is valid
    eng.getRecoveredMessage(); // get the recovered message, only after successful signature verification
```